# What does this sed command mean?

Tags: sed

Can someone please help me interpret the following Linux Sed command?

```
 sed -i '' 's#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#' src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro
```

I cheerfully admit that I find sed command syntax to be very obscure, and reading the sed man page hasn't helped me much so far. When I execute the above command I get this error:

```
sed: can't read s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#: No such file or directory
```

So obviously sed interprets the third argument as a file name - is this the file to be modified? From the sed man page I see that `-I` means to edit the target file in place.

The second argument is the empty string `""` - the man page says this is "script-only-if-no-other-script" but doesn't explain what that means. The last argument `src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro` - I know that a leading `s/` means find and replace, but what does `src/` mean?

Comment: Please check that command was supposed to be a 'Linux' command. Most Linuxes use GNU sed, where edit-in-place suffix, if any, is part of the `-i` argument not separate, but your command has them seperate as used on _BSD_ (and Mac) sed. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401905/bsd-sed-vs-gnu-sed-and-i and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92895/how-can-i-achieve-portability-with-sed-i-in-place-editing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `src/` is just the directory where `qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro` should be.

The Sed command is fairly simple but — like most command line things — can seem more complicated than it is.

```
sed -i "" "s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#" src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro
```

- `-i`: Means to run the command against files in place; meaning just overwrite it.
- `""`: Would be the file extension to use when doing in place editing for backups. But as the man page says, “If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.” That basically implies that whatever follows the `-I` is not optional. So the `""` effectively nulls that value to a zero-length extension so backups are no longer saved. Note that this is how it is used on BSD (and macOS) and not GNU tools used by Linux; in that case `-i` alone would suffice.
- `"s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#"`: In Sed, anything that follows the first `s` in the pattern is used as a delimiter. In this case it will replace any/all occurrences of `__OPENGL_LIBS__` with the value of `-lGL -lGLU`.
- `src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro`: This is simply the full path to the file to be Sed-ded. So when you as what `src/` means, it’s simply the directory path that should contain `qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro`.

Note that while this command works on the BSD version of Sed that is installed on systems such as macOS, it will fail on GNU systems due to the `-i ""`. On GNU systems that `-i ""` should simply be `-i` like this:

```
sed -i "s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#" src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro
```

Knowing that it seems like your error is attempting to run that BSD variant of the command with GNU. Look at the error:

```
sed: can't read s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#: No such file or directory
```

With that extraneous `""` there Sed on GNU would interpret that `""` as the Sed command and think that `"s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#"` is the file path.

---

**Extra**: In the comments you ask:

> “Anyone know how best to write a portable autoscript that uses Sed?”

I don’t know the specifics of your script or the goals of it, but in my own Bash scripts — that I develop in macOS and then use on Linux systems as well, I have a chunk of code like this near the top of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

################################################################################
# Set script variables based on OS specific values.
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^darwin ]]; then
  # For macOS
  sed_options='-i ""';
else
  # For Linux
  sed_options='-i';
fi
```

And then — again using your example command — I would do something like this:

```
sed ${sed_options} "s#__OPENGL_LIBS__#-lGL -lGLU#" src/qt-mbgrdviz-3/qt-mbgrdviz-3.pro
```

Note how I replaced the `-i ""`/`-i` with `${sed_options}`. That way I can concentrate on core script coding when I code on macOS and not have to worry about things choking on Linux systems.

Comment: Note `-i ""` as two arguments only works on BSD (and Mac) sed, which it doesn't appear OP is using.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the info! So on GNU would `-i` alone be enough to tell the command not to create a backup file? I assume so based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401928/30848) from a comment you posted to the original question.

Comment: Please note that my post originally showed a sed command that didn't correspond to the sed error message in the post. I've fixed that - very sorry for the confusion everybody.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is indeed caused by differences between MacOS and Linux GNU 'sed' versions. The sed command that I posted is in a autotools configure.ac script that was written for MacOS, and I was executing that script on Linux, and Linux sed is confused by a space between '-i' and the backup file replacement. Anyone know how best to write a portable autoscript that uses sed?